# Eager fetch using Anorm

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to do eager fetch with **Anorm**, this is lazy fetch like here https://gist.github.com/guillaumebort/2788715

```
package models

import java.util.Date

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current

// table users
case class User(id: Option[Long] = None, firstName: Option[String], lastName: Option[String]) {

  // mismatch types Set[Nicknames] and List[Nicknames] because * returns List
  lazy val nickNames: Set[Nicknames] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL"""
       SELECT * FROM nicknames
       JOIN types t ON nicknames.type_id = t.id
       JOIN events e ON nicknames.events_id = e.id
       WHERE user.id = $id
    """.as(Nickname.withTypeAndEvents.*)
  }
}

object User {
  val simple = {
    get[Option[Long]]("users.id") ~
      get[Option[String]]("users.first_name") ~
      get[Option[String]]("users.last_name") map {
      case id ~ firstName ~ lastName => User(id, firstName, lastName)
    }
  }

  def findById(id: Long): Option[User] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id".as(simple.singleOpt)
  }
}

// table nicknames
case class Nickname(id: Option[Long] = None, name: Option[String], startDate: Option[Date],
                    nType: Option[NickType] = None,
                    user: Option[User] = None,
                    events: Option[Set[Event]] = None) // I use Set here to remove duplicates

object Nickname {
  val simple = {
    get[Option[Long]]("nicknames.id") ~
      get[Option[String]]("nicknames.name") ~
      get[Option[Date]]("nicknames.start_date") map {
      case id ~ name ~ startDate => Nickname(id, name, startDate)
    }
  }

  val withTypeAndUser = simple ~ NickType.simple ~ User.simple map {
    case nick ~ nType ~ user => nick.copy(nType = Some(nType), user = Some(user))
  }

  val withTypeAndEvents = withTypeAndUser ~ Event.simple map {
                                         // it's wrong I think
    case nick ~ event => nick.copy(events = Some(Set(event))) 
  }
}

// table types
case class NickType(id: Option[Long] = None, name: Option[String])

object NickType {
  val simple = get[Option[Long]]("types.id") ~ get[Option[String]]("types.name") map {
    case id ~ name => NickType(id, name)
  }
}

// table events
case class Event(id: Option[Long] = None, regDate: Option[Date], description: Option[String],
                 user: Option[User] = None)

object Event {
  val simple = {
    get[Option[Long]]("events.id") ~
      get[Option[Date]]("events.reg_date") ~
      get[Option[String]]("events.description") map {
      case id ~ regDate ~ description => Event(id, regDate, description)
    }
  }
}
```

I need that findById return my User with nicknames using eager fetch not lazy.

User -> Nicknames use One To Many relation

Nicknames -> User use Many To One relation join column user_id

Nicknames -> Events use One To Many relation

Events -> Nicknames use Many To One relation join column event_id

Comment: What you by eager fetch? Anorm has no object cache so any query is directly executed against connection. Do you have any issue? If yes would you mind giving details on issue.

Comment: I can't properly handle SQL with JOINS (query above) I need return `Set[Nicknames]`, official Anorm documentation contains only simple examples. I know that anorm isn't ORM but how to handle such queries?

Comment: Not being an ORM is the key point. About JOIN, just write them as you would execute it in PostgreSQL by hand (e.g. with psql), and then for the parsing of joined data fetched by executing such query, you combine parsers already defined for separate table. Combining parser is the way to go I think.

Comment: I know how to combine parsers but how to handle queries with multiple JOINS and complex models (e.g. that contains collections)?

Comment: I don't see your point? Knowing combination of parsers, approach when you combine 2 parsers is the same with more parsers, more JOIN.

Comment: I need to return `Set[Nicknames]` look at Nickname.withTypeAndEvents parser I can't properly handle collections of events. Official docs doesn't describe how to work with models which contains collections.

Comment: As soon as you have Nickname parser you can parse Set [Nickname]. Having it as property on a parent entity just mean using this set parser from a parent parsing to aggregate per parent entity instance. I suggest to use Anorm streaming to parse different Nickname columns joined with same parent column. Anorm doc explains streaming, to parse complex data in custom way without having everything in memory, calling exiting parsers when appropriate.

Comment: I tried already use fold and foldWhile but it didn't help me. I can easy handle simple queries like `Select count(*) as c from Country` without JOINS. Can you give me a small example please?

Comment: First `fold` and `foldWhile` won't be available until next Play release (2.3.3). As for current streaming support (`apply` with `Stream[Row]`), you can look at [Acolyte/Anorm 10 minutes tutorial](https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/tree/10m-anorm-tutorial#acolyteanorm-10-minutes-tutorial).

Comment: Oh no, it's a very difficult sample and your 10 min. tutorial is useless for beginners =(
I found this [tutorial](https://github.com/dmanchester/play-hierarchical-data) may be it's not perfect as your solution but easier for me. But anyway thanks.

Comment: I think you try to run before walking. Starting with complexity before being at ease with simple case.

Comment: You're speaking of 'beginner' and 'newcommer', and on other side you want to solve complex situation... You can't complain that existing tutorials don't fit your need and that you're unable to adapt them for... Please be coherent and try to understand how it works, without think it should behave as other libs (ebean, jpa, ...) instead of looking for a made to order solution in such custom case. This discussion is just useless, so good luck.